# How to break up 1 program into multiple file classes in Java?

Tags: java, class, jframe

I have the following program, user has number between 0 and 100. Computer must try to guess it, using binary search algorithm.

When run it creates .class files, but how do i have the classes in separate java files.

```
  public class GuessGame extends JFrame //implements ActionListener
{
    private JButton newGameButton, highButton, lowButton, correctButton, exitButton;
    private JTextField guessBox;
    private JLabel initialTextLabel, enterLabel;
    private JTextArea commentTextArea;
    private JScrollPane scroll;
    //guess is equal to half the highest number
    private int guess=50, high = 101, low = 0, tries;

    public GuessGame()
    {
        super("Guessing Game");
        //add buttons etc.
        //set the layout manager
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        //add components
        //set default jframe size
        setSize(400, 300);

        newGameButtonHandler nghandler = new newGameButtonHandler();
        newGameButton.addActionListener(nghandler);

        exitButtonHandler exithandler = new exitButtonHandler();
        exitButton.addActionListener(exithandler);

        highButtonHandler higherhander = new highButtonHandler();
        highButton.addActionListener(higherhander);

        lowButtonHandler lowerhander = new lowButtonHandler();
        lowButton.addActionListener(lowerhander);

        correctButtonHandler correcthander = new correctButtonHandler();
        correctButton.addActionListener(correcthander);

    }//end of GuessGame constructor

    //highButtonHandler class
    class highButtonHandler implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
                high = guess;
                guess = low + (guess - low) / 2;
                tries++;
                commentTextArea.append("Is the number " + guess + " too small, too high or correct.\n");
        }
    }//end of high class
```

Comment: Place your classes under the same package by declaring above your import statements i.e. `package guessgame;`

Comment: I'm sorry i don't really understand you. Do i put package guessgame above the import statement and then put the code for the class high into a new file and save. How do i call it.

Comment: Yes, and when you move `class highButtonHandler` into a new file, declare the same package in it. All the classes in the same package must have the same package declaration at the very top.

Comment: See also: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/managingfiles.html